# php regular expression to match first word between space and point

Tags: php, regex

I have a string. there I need get a one word. this word is between space and point. for example

```
' 'word.
```

if it find many same pattern words, I need only first word.

Comment: So you want to capture `'word`?

Comment: Is the single quote part of the word or not?

Comment: Please when asking for a regex, always define clear rules for what it should capture and what it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, you could try :

```
/\s(\w+)\./

preg_match('/\s(\w+)\./', 'abc. def. ghi.', $m);
echo $m[1],"\n";
```

output:

```
def
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx):

```
echo pattern(' \w+\.')->match($yourString)->first();
```